# why is my else statement not working but the first statement is?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do not understand how the second if statement will not work even when the first if statement is false. Surely the else statement should be saying "if the statement above is true do nothing. if the statement above me is false then do this". I have tried elseif together and still haven't had any joy with it :S

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

$selectQuery = "SELECT username, email, tokens, tokenstatus, 
                       tokensinc, tokenstatus1, tokenswith, 
                       tokenstatus2 
                FROM members 
                WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username']) ."'";

$updateQuery = "UPDATE members SET tokens=tokens - 10, 
                      tokenstatus='(Pending Tokens)',
                      tokenswith=tokenswith + 10, 
                      tokenstatus1='(Pending Tokens)' 
                WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username']) ."'";

// Create connection
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$db) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()) {
   header('Location: login.php'); exit(); 
}

//define page title
$title = 'Withdraw ~ Pixel Jag';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php');
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<?php


$result = mysqli_query($db, $selectQuery);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  echo "<ul class='list-group'>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['tokens'] < 10) {
        echo "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-danger'>"
              ."You do not have enough tokens!</li>";
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}

/*This is the code that refuses to work for me with the else statement. 
  It works if I take it out but the problem is it allows to go -tokens 
  on the user balance even though the first if error message shows.*/

else {
  if (mysqli_query($db, $updateQuery)) {
    echo "<ul class='list-group'>"
         ."<li class='list-group-item list-group-item success'>"
         ."<h4>Record updated successfully!</h4></li></ul>";
  } 
  else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
  }
}
mysqli_close($db);
?>

<div class="panel-footer">
<a href="index.php"><h4>Back To Dashboard..</h4></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
//include header template
require('layout/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: You should indent properly. The code structure would be clearer. It's also unclear how the second snippet of code connects to the first.

Comment: good tip, it's a bit sloppy

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to understand your code properly because both seem to have been cut off..

Comment: i have commented half way through and it has come out in 2 boxes.. just connect the 2 together it is both part of tokens.php

Comment: If the SELECT query doesn’t return any rows for ‘username’ you fall down to the else clause where you try to run an UPDATE query for the same user that doesn’t exist in the db so of course it doesn’t work.